# Scrollview is different on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xaml, maui

I've been struggling with scrollview on ios. When I run my program on Android, everything works fine, but on IOS scrollview is so wide. To be precise, scrollview on android is wide as the screen is, but on IOS, the scrollview is three times wider than actual screen width. Overall, everytime when I do any layout on Android, everything looks good and works properly, but when I switch the emulator to IOS, the layout is completely different and ruined. Does anybody know what can cause this behavior?

Here is the xaml code:

```
 <RefreshView BackgroundColor="#0F0F0F"
                 Command="{Binding GetPostCommand}"
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" >
        <ScrollView>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding mainPost}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MainPostJson">
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="6,80,6,0">
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto,auto,*,*" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="38" HeightRequest="38" Margin="7"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="16"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Date}" Grid.Column="2" TextColor="#8A8A8A" FontSize="10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="12,4,0,0"/>
                                <Label Text="..." Grid.Column="4" TextColor="White" FontSize="24" Padding="0,0,10,10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding MainImage}" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Black"/>
                            <Grid HeightRequest="130" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowDefinitions="*,*,*" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Topic}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextColor="White" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Line Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="10,0" BackgroundColor="#AEAEAE" HeightRequest="0.5"/>
                                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Image Source="like_icon_red.png" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="10,0"/>
                                    <Label VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding Likes}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" FontSize="14"/>
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Image Source="sharepost_icon.png" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Row="2" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="10,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
```

I've been searching for two days and no answers found.

Comment: “the layout is completely different and ruined” - please provide a more specific description than this.  Screenshots illustrating the problem would be helpful.  And a CollectionView is inherently scrollable so there should be no need to enclose it in a ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code can reproduce this. But for your case, it's not recommended to wrap a vertically-scrolling CollectionView inside a vertically-scrolling ScrollView, which may cause many scrolling issues. **CollectionViews** have their own scrolling built in so you don't have to put it in a ScrollView just as Jason said. Or you may set a **WidthRequest** for CollectionView.

For more info, you could refer to : [How to use CollectionView inside a ScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133556).

Hope it works for you.